# how to align smooth-scrollbar with other plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using AOS for animations and jarallax for parallax.
I use both of them in my website.

Now, I want to add nice scrollbar like [smooth-scrollbar](https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/).

The problem is [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) and [jarallax](https://github.com/nk-o/jarallax) are listen to resize and scroll events from window object. and smooth-scrollbar doesn't trigger this event because its nature. (the height window is 100% - so it can be scrolling, but the inner div is height higher than body.), So both AOS and jarallax doesn't work.

Is any way to make it work together?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you can add event listeners to listen to their custom scroll event.

```
scrollbar.addListener((status) => {
    ...
});
```

(https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/blob/a35ec6fcef35d4363b4be7c08e2ce9db022953fa/docs/api.md#scrollbaraddlistener)

So you can use that to trigger the normal scroll event something like this.

```
scrollbar.addListener((status) => {
    $(window).trigger('scroll');
});
```